# VLC Compilation Mac OS

Tags: compilation, makefile, vlc

I'm trying to compile `VLC` by myself as described [here](http://wiki.videolan.org/OSXCompile#Build_VLC_with_a_single_command) and the `build.sh` throw this error

```
make  all-am
  CCLD     libvlccore.la
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      __nl_find_msg in libintl.a(dcigettext.o)
     (maybe you meant: _vlc_iconv_open, _vlc_iconv , _vlc_iconv_close )
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      __nl_find_msg in libintl.a(dcigettext.o)
     (maybe you meant: _vlc_iconv_open)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [libvlccore.la] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

And I have not the single clue of what I should do. I'm running `Mac OS 10.8.4` and `Xcode 4.6.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to remove references to existing package managers like fink or macports in your environment.

For this, use these commands before doing anything else:
https://wiki.videolan.org/OSXCompile#3rd_party_packagers_and_PATH

Comment: I gave up like 11 months ago :) but thanks, has Homebrew is installed on my computer, it might be this